# Users are asking for too many fields

Tags: custom-object, administration, metadata

I have an custom object that has over 200 custom fields in an org, and growing. Just yesterday we added 4 new fields to this custom object. It is used to contain data from multiple parties outside our company. The reason we keep adding more fields, is there are situations when 10% of our outside parties need specific data about the object, then another 10% need unique data stored about object as well, etc. People keep requesting more fields, and I know we are going to hit a wall soon with the custom field limit.

There are multiple unique formulas fields just for 10% of outside parties, and some unique text fields just for 3% of outside parties. It's getting out of hand.

I feel I shouldn't have to create a custom object for each party, and link it to the custom object that all parties use, or should I? What is Salesforce best practice for this situation?

The gist: when a user needs a unique calculation or data stored on an object that only applies to a minority of the people that use the object, what should be done?

Comment: In what way is the data from those fields being provided to the outside parties?

Comment: @JaredT the internal team uses reports on the object, then reports to the outside parties.

Comment: dump the data and ask them to learn/use excel.

Comment: If that's the case I think it would suffice to say you can do nearly anything with it. Visualforce, some ETL tool, Excel, chicken-scratch on a napkin...

Comment: I'll also say that my org recently had our max number of fields on the Opportunity object increased. From 500. To 1000.